# Simplifying polynomials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials

I have noticed a strange behaviour in Mathematica regarding simplifying polynomial expressions.
Take the following polynomials

```
pol1=3-8s+4s^2
pol2=(2s-1)(2s-3)
```

these two polynomials are equals. However, If I try to simplify the `pol1` I do not get `pol2`

```
pol1//FullSimplify
(*Output: 3 - 8 s + 4 s^2*)
```

Why does this happen? I have always used `FullSimplify` for this kind of expressions. For example,

```
pol3=-15 + 41 s - 24 s^2 + 4 s^3;
pol3//FullSimplify
(*Output: (-3 + s) (-5 + 2 s) (-1 + 2 s) *)
```

Comment: You could use `Factor`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks this is the answer! Thanks ;)

Comment: By default FullSimplify uses LeafCount as the ComplexityFunction. This means that the expression which has more leaves is considered more complex. With this understanding we can reconcile the results that you get.

Comment: @Lotus thanks! So, is it always better to use `Factor`, right?

Comment: @apt45 If you want to factor a polynomial then yes, use Factor !

Comment: See [`Structural Operations on Polynomials`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StructuralOperationsOnPolynomials.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Factor` as stated in the comments:

```
pol1 // Factor
```

> (-3 + 2 s) (-1 + 2 s)

Comparing the polynomials reveals:

```
(pol1 // Factor) === (pol2 // Factor) (* factoring pol2 just equalizes sorting of terms *)
```

> True

[`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) is used by [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) to judge whether an expression is *simpler* than another. We may tweak this (maybe naively) by trying to maximize the number of expressions with the head `Times`:

```
f[e_] := -Count[ e, _Times, {0, Infinity} ]

FullSimplify[ pol1, ComplexityFunction -> f ]
```

> (-3 + 2 s) (-1 + 2 s)

Answer (score 2):

You can see that they are equal by using `FullSimplify` on *both* polynomials.

```
FullSimplify@pol1
```

> `3 + 4 (-2 + s) s`

```
FullSimplify@pol2
```

> `3 + 4 (-2 + s) s`

Furthermore, you can `Reduce` the expression of equality with regard to `s`:

```
Reduce[pol1 == pol2, s]
```

> `True`

Comment: I know they are equal... I was just wondering why Mathematica is not simplifying properly `pol1`.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I misread your question! I'll leave this here for posterity 